# How do I optimize this EF query and implement paging?

Tags: vb.net, paging, asp.net-mvc-5.1, entity-framework-6.1

I have about 14,000 rows of data. If use the following EF query, its a long time to load because I suspect it is loading all 14,000 rows and only then is any additional filtering done. This is my Select method in my repository.

```
Public Function SelectAll() As IEnumerable(Of be_Posts) Implements IPostRepository.SelectAll
       Dim posts As IEnumerable(Of be_Posts)
       Using db As Ctx = New Ctx
           posts = db.be_Posts.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.DateCreated).ToList
           Return posts
       End Using
```

And Controller:

```
Function Index(page As Integer?) As ActionResult
        Dim PageSize = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PageSize")
        Dim pageNumber As Integer = If(page, 1)
        Dim posts = _repo.SelectAll()
        Return View(posts.ToPagedList(pageNumber, PageSize))
    End Function
```

Helper in View:

```
@Html.PagedListPager((Model), Function(page) Url.Action("Index", New With { _
       .page = page _
        }), PagedListRenderOptions.ClassicPlusFirstAndLast)
```

Now If add in a `take` clause, for example `.Take(500)` then things are dramatically faster. How can I make this query faster and still work will all the records? I am also using Troy Goode's PagedList extension to get paging functionality. Everything is fine as long as i get just a few hundred records. So what to do? Most if not all examples of paging that I can find that use Troy's library involve all the code directly in the controller.

Comment: Is there some sort of index on date created so SQL Server can efficiently find the first X records? And you should be returning an IQueryable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `ToList` executes the query and, as you say, it's getting every record.  Paging is done using `Skip` and `Take`, e.g.

```
Dim page = list.Skip(pageSize * (pageNumber - 1)).Take(pageSize)
```

The source list can be the table itself or the result of a `Where` or `OrderBy` call or whatever.  Just make sure that `ToList` or, preferably, `ToArray` is called last.

Comment: How do i pass the pageSize and PageNumber into the repository from the view/controller?

Comment: How would you pass filter values?  You do it the same way.

Comment: I got it working. Skip and Take are working fine. Now just having trouble with the getting the pager helper to render.